# Backup of a Debian machine to an Apple Time Capsule

Tags: backup, time-capsule, unix

I have two Macs, backed up on a 3TB Apple Time Capsule. But I also have a Debian machine on the same local network, and I would like to *back it up* (at least one of its hard disks) *on the same Apple Time Capsule*. Is this possible?

To prevent misunderstandings: I found zillions of places on the Web where people explain how to use a Debian machine as a cheaper version of Apple Time Capsule. This is *not* what I need. What I need is to *back up the Debian machine on a (real) Apple Time Capsule*. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: The time capsule can be mounted as a drive via AFP but note that in Debian you can have files that differ by just case so multiple files would map to one on the TC so not a safe backup

Comment: @Mark: Debian supports both case-sensitive and case-insensitive filesystems, so it might be ok. Definitely something to take note of, though.

Comment: @0942v8653 Wrong way round what matters is HFS which is case insensitive so only case insensitive Debian would work and that is not standard

Comment: @Mark: That's what I meant. I didn't know that Debian's FS was case-sensitive by default. It just depends on how it's configured.

Comment: @0942v8653 It is more than a simple choice OS X can run on either and a few things won't work I suspect on a Debian FS with cases insensitive a lot of things won't work

Comment: Just to add a tidbit: The HFS file System can be set to case sensitive (as opposed to case-preserving, which is the default) during file system creation.

Answer (score 2):

In AirPort Utility, turn off the backup feature, turn off disk encryption, and turn on disk sharing with a password. Now you can connect to the disk over the network using the AFP protocol.

In most graphical file explorers you can now connect to the disk using the address `afp://<ip-address-of-airport>`. To easily configure scheduled backups to the device, you can check out [Déjà Dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DejaDup) (known as simply “Backup” in Ubuntu).

You *cannot* backuo your Macs using Time Machine and your Linux machine to the same device. The two setups are incompatible as Time Machine requires proprietary extension to AFP. I would recommend you get a cheap Raspberry Pi and a two-terabyte power-over-USB-external-disk to host your Linux backup needs. (Install openssh and ufw, and you’re basically done setting up a simplistic firewalled backup device on the cheap.)